# What the name of the evacuated glass gadget with black and white vanes that turn when a light is applied?

Tags: visible-light, terminology, instrument, radiation-pressure

I remember a glass device my physics teacher had at high school which

1. Contained some vanes mounted somehow on a vertical axis, which were all black on one side and white on the other
2. Was in a vacuum (partial, at least)
3. Caused the vanes to spin when a light was shone onto them

I've never seen such a device since. Can anyone tell me if it has a name?

Comment: For UK readers, Crookes Radiometers used to be on sale in the Science Museum Shop [ http://www.sciencemuseumshop.co.uk/home.html#1 ] in South Kensington, London. Searching on that web site, I can find no sign of them there this year; but there are plenty of other gadgets and ideas for Christmas presents to stimulate the interest of young possible future Nobel prize winners ;-P

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is called a [Crookes radiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer) or a light mill.

Comment: I've edited it to say "Crookes radiometer", as there are other types of radiometer that work differently. I hope that's OK.